# Ignore the part [^\\] in Lua pattern

Tags: luatex, strings

I want to find `char $` using lua features, but only if there is no `\` char before `char $`. For this I create the pattern:

```
([^\\]?)%$
```

However, Lua ignores the first part of my pattern and finds only `%$`. Please help me to solve my problem.

Yes, I know that lua has a very bad pattern parser, but I hope I can find `$` if it is either the first character of the line or if it does not have `\` before. Thanks so very much for the help.

Comment: Could you please post a small example document that can be used to reproduce the problem? You seem to use an optional quantifier `?`, so the group can be skipped by the regex matcher if it is not present.

Comment: @siracusa ok,for example in formula \$a-b=0\$ it find two $,but it mustn't do it. ? i used,because $ can be in start of line,so in this case no character before $.

Comment: I will just reiterate, what people on this site have already told you countless times: **It won't work!** You can't capture math mode like that.

Comment: @Henri Menke But if i use nodes,i can't do structure tree. If i use \grabinline or \grabdisplay,i get an errors,when i use,for example,equation environment. I almost solve my problem,using process_input_buffer,but i can't solve problem,when before $ we have \,because matcher ignore my group and i not understand,how to fix it.

Comment: @HenriMenke I think that for the problem at hand it would be okay if luatex would at input replace the first explicit $ by \( and the next by \) while ignoring \$ and $$.

Comment: Please edit your question or title  to make it clear if you are asking about Lua patterns or if you have loaded a Lua regex library (the syntax and functionality of Lua patterns and regular expressions are quite different), also make it clearer what you try to match, originally you say "before it no char" which I would take to mean beginning of line, but later you say "char not equals ."

Comment: @David Carlisle i use lua patterns. About Character i mean,that if before $ we have \,my regex mustn't works,but if we have nothing or any other characters,it must works. The similar thing i did for comments,ie if it exists % and before it no character \,all $ and $$ after this position are ignored. I almost did it,but my regexp works even if before $ or % i have \. Help me please solve this problem. Because now my solution works even if we have $ or $$ on one line and close it in other line,but if before $ we have \,it not ignore. My regexp i wrote in the first message of this topic.

Comment: Lua patterns are _not_ regular expressions, so the title (and your comments mentioning regex) are very confusing.

Comment: @David Carlisle Ok,but why my pattern not works?

Comment: You can only apply `?` to character classes like `%d` as far as I can see.

Comment: @David Carlisle Ok,but what char i must use instead of ?,if i want to use my own char class ie with []?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Do it in stages as I showed, if you first replace every `\$` by something else then you do not need to account for it in your main matching pattern. (it may be possible to construct a single pattern but makes it harder to understand)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear and there are no regular expressions involved here (Lua patterns are quite distinct from regex)

But I think you are looking for something like this, which prints a string involving `\$` and `$` and then prints it with the `\$` still intact but all unquoted `$` replaced.

```
z="aaa \\$ $ x=1$"

print(z)

tmp=string.gsub(z,'\\%$', 'QUOTEDOLLAR')

tmp=string.gsub(tmp,'%$', '!!!')

newz=string.gsub(tmp,'QUOTEDOLLAR', '\\$' )

print(newz)
```

executing this with `texlua` produces the terminal output

```
aaa \$ $ x=1$
aaa \$ !!! x=1!!!
```

Comment: No,i want,that for example line 1$ replace on 1\( or 1\) (depend of setuation),or for example line $a replace on \(a or \)a depends of setuation. It works for me,but if i have,for example,line \$a must be the same,but with my regex it not works and it replace on \\( or \\) (depends of situation),so the condition of my regexp ([^\\]?) ignored.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy you only asked about pattern matching your question makes no mention of what you want to do with the match, I just used replace to `!!!` as an example, The technique is the same, first replace every `\$`  with a "safe string" then do whatever you want to do then change the safe string back to `\$`. (please stop calling these regexp!!)

Comment: Ok,how i must call this instead of regex. As for your idea,it very difficult to find line,which not exists in documents. For example i can replace each \$ on \(,but this part of line can be exists in document,so your method not always give correct results. Ok,advice me please good regexp library for lua,which compatible with lualatex.

Comment: But it exists very small probability,that this line will be in document. Also i replace $ and $$ not on the whole line,but only before meeting %,ie if it exists comments,in which we have $ or $$,it mustn't replace by anymore. So i also check,that before % i haven't \. Yes,i can,probably,for $ and % chack,if before it exists \,using indexes of search,but this do my code more longer,so i want to do it with lua patterns or regexp,but i dont know regex library for lua,which compatible with lualatex.

Comment: Ok,it's a very pitty,that lua patterns ignore my first part of regex. I not wanted use your idea,because in this case my code will be more longer and i hope,that someone advice to me good regex library for lua,but now i will use your idea. About catcodes,maybe it exists way understood in lua,what catcode have $ or another character in this moment to avoid failing of my code. In one document i noticed,that exists chars \\$,ie $ before which we have double \. Can i replace \\$ on $ in this case,or $ with double \ it another command?

Comment: Yes,it's a very pitty,but you right. In python ? ignores to for classes of characters. So,if it ignores ? in regex,i myself think another more best solution. I will concatinate,for example,space char at the start of line,and after that i can only look,that before $ must exists one any character,except \. After my manipulation i will return substring,which will contains whole string,except first character. But i not understand,what i must do,if before $ i will see double \?

Comment: O no,([^\\])%$ not works for me to. Why this happends? This construction must work,but it not works.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy in the regex version `?` isn't ignored but as it includes 0 times,  `([^\\]?)\$` matches the `$` in `\$` with `[^\\]?` matching the empty string between `\ ` and `$`, but there are too many comments here I am going to delete most of them.

Comment: Ok,i know,that $ in regex it end of line,and i set before it \ or % (depends of language of programming),but i not understoode,why before $ and \ exists empty character and how to fix it,i mean,using regex,for example on python,because for lua,as i understoode,there is no variant,besides your variant. And as i wrote,now i not use ?,but it not works,ie even $ not replaced in lua.

Comment: Sorry,the regex without ? works ok,. It was bug in my code,which not allow to use result of works of my regex. So it seems,what we can close this question.